# Adding confirmed to a nearly complete rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, confirm

I am coming to the end of my rails project now and I have done everything I wish to do apart from confirm the users account through email before creating it. I already have it to send an email to the user but I want the user to contain a link. It's far too late to add devise now as I already have a users table etc.

I have heard of having a confirmed field in the users table and having it set to false and then true on user confirmation, but I have no idea on how to implement this. Any ideas?

If anyone else has some other solutions or links to tutorials showing how to add such feature then that would be outstanding. The end is so close yet so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never too late to add devise. If I were you, I'd do exactly this.

But, if I were to implement confirmation functionality myself, this is how I would go about this:

1. For each user, make a hash (as in MD5 hash). There are many ways: 1) for each user generate its own and store in a dedicated table column; 2) make one out of password salt, user id and (optionally) some static strings; 3) something else.
2. Send a user an email with a link, which contains his id and that hash.
3. When someone hits your confirmation url, you extract user id and hash from query string, and compare them with what you have. If they match, then you mark user as confirmed.

Comment: Cheers Sergio, do you have any tutorials on doing this, then only previous hash I have used was the the password_hash which I gathered out of a rails tutorial so have had no other experience of doing such. In regards to adding devise. Would I simply migrate t.confirmable to the users file? and then add devise :confirmable to the to of the user model? is it that simple? I have already got a devise initializier (default one).

Comment: I didn't use Devise with mysql, so don't know about what migrations are necessary. But nothing stops you from trying. I'd say, it's one hour of work, tops.

Comment: In regards to your suggestion, do you have any links to a tutorial etc showing how to implement such features?